# using function into typeorm consult

Tags: typescript, typeorm

I have the next code:

```
const CompaniesRelation: Array<CompanyRelation> = await getRepository(CompanyRelation).find({ where:{ UserId: data.UserId, IsActive: true} });
```

it should return me an array with objects like this:

```
[{CompanyId"a"},{CompanyId"b"},{CompanyId"c"}]
```

My next step is:

```
const ids: Array<string> = CompaniesRelation.map(c => c.CompanyId);
```

and I need to use it into an TypeOrm select,where I need to select all about a table, where the arrays is equals to the Ids between COmpany and CompaniesRelation

```
 const CompanyData: Array<Company> = await getRepository(Company).find({ where:{ CompanyId: data.UserId IN(´${JSON.stringify(ids).slice(1, -1)}´) } });
```

So the syntaxis for it is wrong, but I'm not sure why, how is the correct syntaxis for it and how can I get the Array that I'm trying?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
const CompanyData: Array<Company> = await getRepository(Company).find({ where:{ CompanyId: In(ids)  } });
```

`In()` is typeorm function